# How can i add to the listView the searching results in real time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My program search for text inside files.
But what i want to do is to see the searching progress in real time.
I want to add the current file name search in to listView and also to display to a progressBar the percentages from 0 to 100%.

I added a backgroundworker but the way i'm using the ReportProgress is not working good. I need to wait for it to finish the foreach in the FindLines method and then only in the end i see the items in the listView and even then the items are a big mess.

This is the line that report:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, fi.Name);
```

This is a screenshot of the items in the listView when the foreach is over:
What i want to do is to display the items adding to the listView in real time without waiting first to the operation over and also to add each item to a line and if a line is too long then later i will add a tip baloon or something. But now the listView look like a big mess.

[image: listView]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Search_Text_In_Files
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"e:\textresults.txt");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();           
        }

        public List<string> FindLines(string DirName, string TextToSearch)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            List<string> findLines = new List<string>();
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(DirName);
            if (di != null && di.Exists)
            {
                if (CheckFileForAccess(DirName) == true)
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    {
                        if (string.Compare(fi.Extension, ".cs", true) == 0)
                        {
                            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, fi.Name);
                            using (StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText())
                            {
                                string s = "";
                                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                                {
                                    if (s.Contains(TextToSearch))
                                    {
                                        counter++;
                                        findLines.Add(s);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                w.Close();
            }
            return findLines;
        }

        private bool CheckForAccess(string PathName)
        {
            // Determine if the path is a file or a directory

            if (File.Exists(PathName) == true)
                return CheckFileForAccess(PathName);

            if (Directory.Exists(PathName) == true)
                return CheckFolderForAccess(PathName);

            return false;
        }


        private bool CheckFileForAccess(string FileName)
        {
            FileSecurity fs = new FileSecurity(FileName, AccessControlSections.Access);
            if (fs == null)
                return false;

            AuthorizationRuleCollection TheseRules = fs.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
            if (TheseRules == null)
                return false;

            return CheckACL(TheseRules);
        }

        private bool CheckFolderForAccess(string FolderName)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(FolderName);
            if (di == null)
                return false;

            DirectorySecurity acl = di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
            if (acl == null)
                return false;

            AuthorizationRuleCollection TheseRules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
            if (TheseRules == null)
                return false;

            return CheckACL(TheseRules);
        }

        private bool CheckACL(AuthorizationRuleCollection TheseRules)
        {
            foreach (FileSystemAccessRule ThisRule in TheseRules)
            {
                if ((ThisRule.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.Read) == FileSystemRights.Read)
                {
                    if (ThisRule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
                        return false;
                }
                // Run as many other checks as you like
            }

            return true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            FindLines(@"d:\c-sharp", "string s1 = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag as string;");
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe try to add call to [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.invalidate(v=vs.110).aspx) after `listView1.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());`

Comment: it would look better if you list only one file in one line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should look into [ObservableCollection(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The collection fires events when items are added to it, and the UI element should automatically detect these changes and update the view.

At least that is how it works in WPF, but i think it should work as well in WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a screenshot of the items in the listView when the foreach is
>   over: What i want to do is to display the items adding to the listView
>   in real time without waiting first to the operation over and also to
>   add each item to a line and if a line is too long then later i will
>   add a tip baloon or something. But now the listView look like a big
>   mess.

Did you try setting your Listview's view property to "List" ? That should display the file names in individual lines.

Comment: this is not the answer to the question